# Fixing the size of Jquery Ui multiselect

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, multi-select

I am using this Jquery Ui multiselect plugin http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_next/. I am trying to put this multiselect in an `html` table cell , but the size of `multiselect` becomes too small . Any help regarding , how to size the the whole `multiselect` so that it could be shown in a table , would be highly appreciated .

Comment: I tried the updated JS file of `Jquery UI Multiselect` from the bug report page . It has `options` of width and height , So if anyone is stuck to the same problem go to the bug report and get the updated ui.multiselect.js file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Jquery Ui multiselect plugin appears to use the height and width values of the select item you are calling it on.

For example if you have a select like:

```
<select id="locations" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="locations[]" style="width:300px; height:300px;">
```

Then call:

```
$(".multiselect").multiselect();
```

Your new multiselect will have 300x300 dimensions.

Comment: thanks for your input, highly appreciate it. Although I haven't tried your solution as I used the updated `JS` file which has options to specify height and width and that solved my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to be, multiselect by default has a min height of 200, or some predefined min height setting. To resolve I did this below which worked for me anyhow. Hope it helps someone else.

```
 $("#ddl_MMS").multiselect({ columns: 1, placeholder: "@Report.ALLMMS", selectAll: true, minHeight:40 });
```